# Query 2 child relationships with 1 subquery

Tags: soql

Below is my data model:

[image: data model]

Menu_Item__c is a full meal you can order (eg. Butter Chicken), and Menu_Item_Ingredient__c is the ingredients to make that (eg. Butter chicken Sauce, Rice, Chicken).

I have a method that accepts a Menu_Item__c as a parameter. I want to query all Menu_Item_Ingredient__c records for that Menu_Item__c, AND I also want to get all the Alergen_Warning__c records for each Menu_Item_Ingredient__c.

**Is it possible to do this in 1 query, or do I have to use 2? Below is an example of what I'm thinking of for trying to get it all with 1 query:**

```
List<Menu_Item_Ingredient__c> menuItemIngredients = [SELECT Name,  //don't think you can do this
            (SELECT Name FROM Alergen_Warnings__r), 
            (SELECT Menu_Item__c, Menu_Item_Ingredient__c FROM Menu_Item_Ingredient_Participations__r) 
            FROM Menu_Item_Ingredient__c 
            WHERE Id IN Menu_Item_Ingredient_Participations__r];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
SELECT Name,
  (SELECT Name FROM Allergen_Warnings__r),
  (SELECT Menu_Item_Ingredient__c FROM Menu_Item_Ingredient_Participations__r)
FROM Menu_Item_Ingredient__c 
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT Menu_Item_Ingredient__c 
  FROM Menu_Item_Ingredient_Participation__c 
  WHERE Menu_Item__c = :menuItemId
)
```

Here, the subquery filter selects the ingredients from the participation table based on the menu item Id, and the requested data is returned using menu item ingredient as the top-level object, with two child relationships.

Comment: Thanks so much, i will try editing my code with this and testing

Comment: It worked perfect, thank you @sfdxfox you're a legend!